# set value for a global variable in local nested function

Tags: javascript, cordova

I have the following function

```
function fileExists(FileName) {
    var retvar="false";
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

      fileSystem.root.getFile(FileName, null,
           function() {
              fileEntry.file(function() {
                 alert("Exists");
              },
              function() {

       });
      },
      function () {
          retvar = "true";
          alert(retvar);  //says true
      });
     },null);

    alert(retvar);  //says false
}
```

here, i have to set the value of retvar as true in the inner nested function. I can't pass that value outside that function. Could any one tell me any idea for passing that value to the parent function?

Comment: Are you using `"true"` and `"false"` as `String`s for a specific reason? Wouldn't it be better to use `true` and `false` directly as `boolean`s?

Comment: i am using it as string only. I need that as string.

Comment: what is the sequence of execution check by adding 1 more hardcoded parameter in alert... May be your outer alert is called first.

Comment: the inner alert is executing first. Just now i checked it by differentiating them by `alert("inner value : " + retvar);` and `alert("outer value : " + retvar);` the inner alert is executing first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh! thanks google! for answering me!

I had to initialize the variable before the function!

The answer should be

```
var retvar="";
function fileExists(FileName) {
    retvar = "false";
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {

      fileSystem.root.getFile(FileName, null,
           function() {
              fileEntry.file(function() {
                 alert("Exists");
              },
              function() {

       });
      },
      function () {
          retvar = "true";
          alert(retvar);  //says true
      });
     },null);

    alert(retvar);  //says same if it is assigned as like in the inner loop
}
```

Comment: Is this only solution? Since it doesn't sound right from OOP point of view to have global variable for every single nested function which needs to return something.